# Angular 2 cross application (root component) communication

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I am searching for a way of interaction between multiple root components living on a page. Background is that I am developing a bunch of modules for a CMS that should be able to share data, consume event or just know about each other if the user decides to add them to the page. Because of the nature of a CMS these components get bootstraped independently.

In Angular 1 exists the possibility to get a reference of a controller class using JQuery:

```
$("#MyApplication").controller();
```

Does Angular 2 somehow provide a similar way or even better approach to let them communicate with each other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a shared service.

```
class SharedService {
  ...
}

var sharedService = new SharedService();

bootstrap(App1, [provide(SharedService, {useValue: sharedService})]);
bootstrap(App2, [provide(SharedService, {useValue: sharedService})]);
```

In the components where you want to communicate with the other Angular application just inject the service

```
constructor(private sharedService:SharedService) {
  sharedService.someObservable.subscribe(...);
  sharedService.someObservable.emit(...);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide plunker example for this? @Gunter

Comment: What about you create a plunker and if you run into issues I have a look and try to fix it?